# Break long string into short pieces for web request

Tags: blackberry

I am converting an image to a base64 string, but that string is too large at about 27000 characters.  When I send the string to the server, I get a response like 
"request entity not found"

Can I break that long string into shorter strings that will be decoded by the server?

Comment: If you converting image then use Byte Array.

Comment: Are you able to change the way the server works to accomodate your long string, or do you have to take server behavior as a given?  Also, as Remy points out, you should be using HTTP Post, not a HTTP Get, for this volume of data.

Comment: You are not sending the base64 string inside a URL, are you? That is WAY too long for a URL to be. Otherwise, a "request entity not found" error has nothing to do with the image data. What exactly are you sending the image data to, and why are you base64 encoding it?